# Hashing issue between guava versions

Tags: hash, guava, sha256

I was using guava 14 to do String hashing like so:

```
Hashing.sha256().newHasher().putString("String").hash().toString();
```

=>

```
4d1ca6dce72e20ce214b706168340683bb6b571a7c977c1a9fe029a1cc1c4d06
```

just upgraded to guava16,

calling this function:
`Hashing.sha256().newHasher().putString("String", Charsets.UTF-8).hash().toString()` gives me a different result.

=>

```
b2ef230e7f4f315a28cdcc863028da31f7110f3209feb76e76fed0f37b3d8580
```

I suspect that the old version was using default charset, but switching Charsets on guava16 doesn't give me the same result as in guava14. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the docs of Guava 15, the replacement for the old `putString(String)` method is `putUnencodedChars`.

Comment: oops, i must have missed it. thanx

Answer (score 1):

As Louis said, the replacement is Hasher.putUnencodedChars(). Or, you can use the shortcuts on the HashFunction interface:

```
Hashing.sha256().hashUnencodedChars("String").toString();
```